# JSON.NET deserialize a specific property

Tags: c#, json.net

I have the following `JSON` text:

```
{
    "PropOne": {
        "Text": "Data"
    }
    "PropTwo": "Data2"
}
```

I want to deserialize `PropOne` into type `PropOneClass` without the overhead of deserializing any other properties on the object. Can this be done using JSON.NET?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
public T GetFirstInstance<T>(string propertyName, string json)
{
    using (var stringReader = new StringReader(json))
    using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(stringReader))
    {
        while (jsonReader.Read())
        {
            if (jsonReader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName
                && (string)jsonReader.Value == propertyName)
            {
                jsonReader.Read();

                var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                return serializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonReader);
            }
        }
        return default(T);
    }
}

public class MyType
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public void Test()
{
    string json = "{ \"PropOne\": { \"Text\": \"Data\" }, \"PropTwo\": \"Data2\" }";

    MyType myType = GetFirstInstance<MyType>("PropOne", json);

    Debug.WriteLine(myType.Text);  // "Data"
}
```

This approach avoids having to deserialize the entire object.  But note that this will only improve performance if the json is ***significantly*** large, and the property you are deserializing is relatively early in the data.  Otherwise, you should just deserialize the whole thing and pull out the parts you want, like jcwrequests answer shows.

Comment: Updated slightly for better re-usability.

Comment: This method is broken in that it will catch the first property "PropOne" anywhere at any level, not just in the root of the tree.  
It can be fixed by keeping track of the level and only accept the correct property name at the root level.

Comment: Note that this can also be useful if you're not sure what the JSON string you're decoding is, and you need to read a property to figure it out.

Answer (score 46):

The JSON isn't too large, so I'll take Matt Johnson's suggestion and deserialize the whole thing. Thanks to jcwrequests answer, I was able to use this method:

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
var jToken = jObject.GetValue("PropTwo");
PropTwoClass value = jToken.ToObject(typeof(PropTwoClass));
```

Comment: This works as well: `var propTwoClass = jToken.ToObject<PropTwoClass>();`

Answer (score 17):

A simpler solution to [Omar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19439146/33236) would be to have a wrapper.

```
class Wrapper
{
    public PropOneClass PropOne;
}

JsonConvert.Deserialize<Wrapper>(json).PropOne
```

My tests found it to be about 30% faster.

Comment: This is a much more flexible approach. Create classes that only have the properties you want to deserialize and it will skip all the bulk on the fly and it runs much faster.

Answer (score 7):

```
 var json = "{ "PropOne": { "Text": "Data" } "PropTwo": "Data2" }";

 JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
 var val = o.PropTwo;
```

Using JSON Linq provider you do not need to deserialize the object into a known type.

Answer (score 2):

[Matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19438910/33236) is by far the fastest solution though it has a bug.
This is my attempt in fixing that.
This method will only return a matching property at the root level.
There is still a naive approach in counting start and end tokens though for valid JSON it will probably work.

Matt, feel free to copy this into your answer.

```
public T GetFirstInstance<T>(string propertyName, string json)
{
    using (var stringReader = new StringReader(json))
    using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(stringReader))
    {
        int level = 0;

        while (jsonReader.Read())
        {
            switch (jsonReader.TokenType)
            {
                case JsonToken.PropertyName:
                    if (level != 1)
                        break;
                    if ((string)jsonReader.Value == propertyName)
                    {
                        jsonReader.Read();

                        return (T)jsonReader.Value; 
                    }
                    break;

                case JsonToken.StartArray:
                case JsonToken.StartConstructor:
                case JsonToken.StartObject:
                    level++;
                    break;

                case JsonToken.EndArray:
                case JsonToken.EndConstructor:
                case JsonToken.EndObject:
                    level--;
                    break;
            }

        }
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Comment: How about skipping the token's children so we only get root level nodes:
`while (jsonReader.Read()) { if ((string)jsonReader.Value == propertyName) { //return } jsonReader.Skip(); }`

Comment: @amolbk yes [Skip](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_Skip.htm) looks like it was added [6 months ago](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) and would simplify the code. Perhaps that is better for a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `JsonIgnore` - this will cause the property to be completely ignored by Json.Net, both for serializing and deserializing.

Also, check this [link](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/10/23/efficient-json-with-json-net-reducing-serialized-json-size).

Comment: I don't have a composite object that contains both `PropOne` and `PropTwo`, rather I have two separate classes that represent `PropOne` and `PropTwo`.

Comment: Are you serializing the objects too?

Comment: If by that you mean I'm the one creating the JSON, then no, the JSON I'm getting is sent by a 3rd party.

Comment: NomadTraveler, do you know if it is possible to have JsonIgnore only for deserializing?