# How to deserialize the whole object but specify a specific method for a property?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

My question is similar to this question - [JSON.NET deserialize a specific property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438472/json-net-deserialize-a-specific-property)
. Except I want to deserialize the whole object but also use a custom method to deserialize a specific property in the class. The way I'm doing it right now is deserializing the whole object, and then calling a custom method again to deserialize a specific property in that object. This works, but I don't think it is very efficient.

```
 public class Foo
 {
     public int id { get; set; }
     public object item { get; set; }
 }

 object obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(Foo));

 //This method is from the previously asked question and it works.
 object item = GetFirstInstance<GenericFoo<object>>("item", json); 

 Foo castedFoo= (Foo)obj;
 castedFoo.item = item;
```

How can I update this code to make it more efficient? Something like ignore item property when the first time the object is getting deserialized?

Comment: Have you tried using a [custom `JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8030538/3744182) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8030538/3744182)?

Comment: @dbc Thanks for the links. I don't think I'm following that example. How do I first deserailzie the whole object (but ignore item property) and then deserialize the item property?

Comment: This sounds like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  You want to deserialize it *correctly*.  Why do you need to deserialize it in two passes if it can be deserialized correctly in one pass?

Comment: @dbc It's a little hard to explain without showing you the whole code but I'll try. The value of the item property is an f# discriminated union tuple. The default deserialize implementation is giving me trouble, so I need to specify the type explicitly for just that one "item" property. Hope that helps.

Comment: @dbc And I don't want to deserailize in two steps. The only reason I'm doing it is because of the f# discriminated union type. Newtonsoft is not inferring the right type.

Comment: What does the JSON look like?