# How to get particular value from .json file

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON file I need to catch a particular key-value to do that here my JSON code

```
{
    "uri": "https://wmg.nfa.futures.org/news/EnforceRegActions5imple.aspx",

      "children": [
    {
        "uri": "https://www.nfa.futures.ortnews/EnforceRegActions5imple.aspx#145View%209%28e1233a13%401",
        "children": [
            {
                "uri": "httpsghomm nfa futures org/news/EnforceReeActions5imple aspx#114Rule4%28e6ea03f2%400%40145View%209%28e1233a13%401",
                "title": "Compliance Rules : Rule 2-2 : Rule",
                "type": "Enforcement and Registration Actions : Rule",
                "publishedDate": "2019-08-15",
                "cachedDateTimeOffset": "0001-01-01700:00:00+00:00",

            },
            {
                "uri": "httos./Pv'm nfa futures ore/news/EnforceReioctions5imple 
          aspx#114Rule4%28e6ea03f2%401%40145view%209%28e1233a13%401",
                "title": "Compliance Rules : Rule 2-4 : Rule",
                "type": "Enforcement and Registration Actions : Rule",
                "publishedDate": "2019-08-15",
                "cachedDateTimeOffset": "0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",

            }
        ]
    "children": [
        {
            "uri": "https://www.nfa.futures.ortnews/EnforceRegActions5imple.aspx#145View%209%28e1233a13%401",
            "children": [
                {
                    "uri": "httpsghomm nfa futures org/news/EnforceReeActions5imple aspx#114Rule4%28e6ea03f2%400%40145View%209%28e1233a13%401",
                    "title": "Compliance Rules : Rule 2-2 : Rule",
                    "type": "Enforcement and Registration Actions : Rule",
                    "publishedDate": "2019-08-15",
                    "cachedDateTimeOffset": "0001-01-01700:00:00+00:00",
                    "html": "<span data-rule-id=\"RULE 2-2\" data-rule-section=\"4\" data-rule-sub-section=\"0\" class.\"btn-add-rule\" data-cube-level=\"2\" data-cube-scope=\"7404961\">Rule</span>"
                },
                {
                    "uri": "httos./Pv'm nfa futures ore/news/EnforceReioctions5imple aspx#114Rule4%28e6ea03f2%401%40145view%209%28e1233a13%401",
                    "title": "Compliance Rules : Rule 2-4 : Rule",
                    "type": "Enforcement and Registration Actions : Rule",
                    "publishedDate": "2019-08-15",
                    "cachedDateTimeOffset": "0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",
                    "html": "<span data-rule-id=\"RuLE 2-4\" data-rule-section=\"4\" data-rule-sub-section=\"0\" class=\"btn-add-rule\" data-cube-level=\"2\" data-cube-scope=\"64787825\">Rule</span>"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see in the Image I need that Html part to catch Using C# Code I was able to get this code as JSON for an object but I cannot select this Html value to a variable

```
  using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("US--NFA--INS--ENFORCE.structure.json"))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            var parsed = JObject.Parse(json);
```

when I debug I can see all the values but I can not select a particular one I also tried SElECTED Token but with no luck.

my problem is this has two children json one has an HTML key other does not have i need to get the first children I need second children that HTML value that what I need but when I nested looping it always selected the first node how to solve this

Comment: simply create the model and then deserialize it and then access value.

Comment: here everything you need to do with json in .net
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: Do you need all the html values or just one?

Comment: @TedBrownlow  all HTML Values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON.NET deserialize a specific property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438472/json-net-deserialize-a-specific-property)

Comment: still, I have not clear working way can anyone suggest away

Comment: @ish1104 your JSON is not valid.

Comment: What did you mean it is working fine this is small part of my json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of below should do the trick.

```
JArray data = (JArray)parsed["children"];

foreach(JObject children in (JObject)data){
  foreach(JObject child in (JArray)children["children"]){
     var value = child["html"];
  }

}
```

Comment: it gives a null Value Child object get all the values I need but it also returns a null value for this var value. Also here I have more than one string for the Html it should store as a list.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the image but you can get by:

```
parsed["key"];
```

Comment: there are several levels of that Jason as example children have several levels the last level has the value that I need

Comment: Use a VPN service like Opera's embedded VPN. Imgur is banned in Turkey.

Comment: @Ömer Baş  it has several levels so I cannot take directly using key I need to go to the last node level of children to get the value

Comment: You can get deeper like parsed["key1"]["key2"]. But if there are several levels, I suggest to create a class then map your json to it.

Thank you @CelalErgün.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this example will help:

```
string json = @"{
  'channel': {
    'title': 'James Newton-King',
    'link': 'http://james.newtonking.com',
    'description': 'James Newton-King\'s blog.',
    'item': [
      {
        'title': 'Json.NET 1.3 + New license + Now on CodePlex',
        'description': 'Announcing the release of Json.NET 1.3, the MIT license and the source on CodePlex',
        'link': 'http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx',
        'categories': [
          'Json.NET',
          'CodePlex'
        ]
      },
      {
        'title': 'LINQ to JSON beta',
        'description': 'Announcing LINQ to JSON',
        'link': 'http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx',
        'categories': [
          'Json.NET',
          'LINQ'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}";

JObject rss = JObject.Parse(json);

string rssTitle = (string)rss["channel"]["title"];

string itemTitle = (string)rss["channel"]["item"][0]["title"];

JArray categories = (JArray)rss["channel"]["item"][0]["categories"];
```

Comment: this is hard coding is there any way to do this by without hardcoding

Comment: I can have two children node frist children node does not contain an HTML key second one has I need to get the second node call to a function.usi.ng Adriani6 answer i able to get the value but it calls the first children data but I need second children data