# Newtonsoft.Json Custom Root Name for Deserialization

Tags: c#, json.net

I have this class that defines the json format:

```
public class ResultType
{
    public bool status { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}
```

The actual json looks like this:

```
{"result":{"status":true,"message":"Success"}}
```

How can I override the root attribute when de-serializing the json to "result"

Comment: You mean you want to deserialize the value of `"result"` without needing an outer wrapper class?  If so, see [Deserializing JSON - how to ignore the root element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702657) or [JSON.NET deserialize a specific property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438472).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserializing JSON - how to ignore the root element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702657/deserializing-json-how-to-ignore-the-root-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a central deserialization method, so I'm trying to avoid type specific code as much as possible.

I used the following to resolve the problem, maybe not as sexy as I was hoping for but it works.

```
public class ResultType
{
    public ResultDetailType result { get; set; }
}
public class ResultDetailType
{ 
    public bool status { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
JObject jsonResponse = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
ResultType _Data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultType>(jsonResponse["result"].ToString());

Console.WriteLine(_Data.status);
```

Fiddle: [https://dotnetfiddle.net/gjYS2p](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MUN2lD)